# Recursive function for a linear recurrence relation runs into recursion error

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I have this recursive function:

```
def My_recu_fun(i):
    if i < 4:
        return i+1
    return 55692*My_recu_fun(i-4) - 9549*My_recu_fun(i-3) + 301*My_recu_fun(i-2) + 21*My_recu_fun(i-1)
```

If I call it like:

```
My_recu_fun(int(2e5))
```

I get this error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Now I hope to solve this by using NumPy. But I don't understand how can I do it.

Comment: you are passing `2e5` and your function has a branching factor of 4. There are not enough atoms in the universe to compute that

Comment: To boost the speed and reduce load - check & use `memorization` or caching for your `My_recu_fun`. Give it a try & share your results.

Comment: In Numpy/pandas, create an array with number from 0 to `2e5`. After that, using rolling sum to use your function to update each x value with x-1, x-2, & x-3 position values

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain the context that led you to want to implement that particular recurrence relation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function will get executed an exponentially number of times, in terms of the initial argument `i`. There is an immense number of times that the function needs to recalculate a result it already had calculated earlier in the process.

Using NumPy can be a good idea when you need to do intensive array/matrix operations, but in itself it will not solve this particular recursion problem.

You could use memoization to avoid such recalculations. But it is even better to take a bottom up, iterative approach, only keeping track of the last 4 results:

```
def My_fun(i):
    if i < 4: 
        return i+1
    a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
    for j in range(3, i):
        a, b, c, d = b, c, d, 55692*a - 9549*b + 301*c + 21*d
    return d
```

Be aware the the numbers that are generated by this function quickly grow very large.

Here are some statistics:

| value of `i` | function result |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 20 | 23654235486457205901623901 (26 digits) |
| 200 | ~10<sup>263</sup> |
| 2000 | ~10<sup>2643</sup> |
| 20000 | ~10<sup>26443</sup> |

Calculating with such large integers, takes lots of memory and time. You cannot use NumPy even with the iterative algorithm, because its native ctypes cannot save numbers that large.

Comment: Since the recurrence relation is linear, this could be further optimized by writing the relation as a vector(n) = matrix . vector(n-1) product. Then you don't need to loop, you can directly exponentiate the matrix, which can be much faster. Sadly we still can't use numpy because of the large integers.

Answer (score 0):

`My_recu_fun(int(2e5))` runs the My_recu_fun more than 2*10^5 (so 200.000) times. Python assumes it is a bug (because it's more than 10^4 times) and wants to prevent it. You can turn that behaviour off using:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(n)
```

Where n is the required amount of recursion. I cannot estimate how many times My_recu_fun does recursion, so you will have to estimate that.

In addition to that, I recommend using functool's cache decorator to speed things up:

```py
import sys
from functools import cache

n = 500000
sys.setrecursionlimit(n)

@cache
def My_recu_fun(i):
    if i < 4: return i+1

    return 55692*My_recu_fun(i-4) - 9549*My_recu_fun(i-3) + 301*My_recu_fun(i-2) + 21*My_recu_fun(i-1)
```

Comment: Hello, for this approch I get  "zsh: segmentation fault" error

Comment: That's probably a memory issue. It's because the program is doing a lot of calculations, like @Sembei Norimaki pointed out.

Comment: "You're attempting to run head-first into a wall of concrete. Python assumes it is a bug and wants to prevent it. You can turn that behaviour off using: ..." Why? Why would you recommend turning that behaviour off? Of course it is a bug!

Comment: @Stef because a program (like this one) is sometimes required to recurse more than 10^4 times.

Comment: @Lau Yes... The OP's program is trying to call approximately `10**120000` recursive calls. That's more than the number of particles in the universe, squared. Good luck fixing that bug with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.